# How catch curl response into variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, groovyshell

I want to curl an URL and capture the response into a variable.

when I curl a command and echo its output I get the correct response as below

```
sh 'output=`curl https://some-host/some-service/getApi?apikey=someKey`;echo $output;'
```

I want to catch the same response into a variable and use that response for further operation

Below is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent {
          label "build_2"
       }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh 'npm install'

            }
        }
        stage('Build-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Building Image..........................'

                //In below line I am getting Output
                //sh 'output=`curl https://some-host/some-service/getApi?apikey=someKey`;echo $output;'

                script {
                    //I want to get the same response here
                    def response = sh 'curl https://some-host/some-service/getApi?apikey=someKey'
                    echo '=========================Response===================' + response
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what changes I need to do in my Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to return an output from `sh` step and capture it in the variable you have to change:

```
def response = sh 'curl https://some-host/some-service/getApi?apikey=someKey'
```

to:

```
def response = sh(script: 'curl https://some-host/some-service/getApi?apikey=someKey', returnStdout: true)
```

*Reference: [https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script_)*

Comment: Thanks, Szymon. It answered my problem statement.